# How to find the current visible controller for SwiftUI HostingController from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swiftui, uihostingcontroller

I am working on a project where initial screens are in SwiftUI and further flow is in UIKit controllers. My problem is I want to know the `visibleController` on the screen or `UINavigationController` of the navigation stack when any of the appDelegate functions (let's say open:URL, performActionFor:shortcutItem) gets triggered.

So for that I tried to use `UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first.rootViewController` but it is giving me as something like this `<_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15>`. So here I m not getting the `UINavigationController` or the current `visibleController`.

So any idea on how to get the `UINavigationController` or the visible `UIViewController` or the **NavigationStack**.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: The `rootViewController` you've got is an instance of `UIHostingController`, which is a subclass of `UIViewController`, so you can use it as usually to present another controller, access navigationController, etc.

Comment: @Asperi When we try to access ```navigationController``` it is nil.